# inverting op amp design

Tags: operational-amplifier

I attached the question as well as my design, I don't know why it does not work( I get no output on simulation). 
could you have a look at it and comment on it? 
Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the polarity of your supplies.  You have one supply at 15V and the other at 12V.  Why is your load resistor connected to the inverting input and not ground? It will reduce your gain.

Comment: Incorrect resistors as well as polarities. Pin 4 should be negative supply, and both should be 15 V i guess. Also, you are using 2V rms, which would result in output pretty close to saturation.

Comment: I modified it but still don't know what the problem is

Comment: The 2K load resistor RL should connect between pin 6 and ground, not between pin 6 and pin 4, where it will appear as part of the feedback resistor.  What do you mean by "no output" - what is the voltage at pin 6?

Comment: And i didn't mean you should remove your 2v rms sine input. Decreasing the amplitude would have done fine as well.

Comment: I changed the Vin back to AC since with Dc I got nothing, but with AC the simulation is okay, but I am not getting the correct gain though( using transient analysis)

Comment: Yes, because 10v rms (after a gain of 5) equals 14.2v peak. Anything above 13v or so is likely to be clipped (practically). Thats why i told you to decrease the amplitude.

Comment: how can I reduce the amplitude? and reduce it to what? alos the question says Vin=0 to 2 V

Comment: You can set 2V max instead of RMS ( I'm talking of input) or use V_rms = V_peak / 1.42

Comment: Well I am using Version 13, and it seems it can only give me rms Ac source

Comment: The peak voltage of a sine wave with 1 volt RMS is sqrt(2), or 1.414.  So set your sine wave amplitude to 2/sqrt(2), or 1.414 volts.

Comment: that's right, now I remember that formula. now that I changed Vin ,it looks simulation is giving me a good looking wave, thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, your load resistor should go to ground, not to the inverting input. Looks like you have fixed the power supply issues as of this post.

The resistor *ratio* is correct, however your resistor **values** are WAY too low. The 200 ohm Rf (in your current schematic) goes to a virtual ground, so it's effectively in parallel with the load resistance of 2K as far as the op-amp output is concerned. It should give you *some* output, but the current limiting will kick in way before you get to 10V on the output. 10V out into 2K\$\Omega\$ || 200\$\Omega\$ = 55mA. That's why you are seeing "clipping" (or at least it should be, depending on how good your model is).

Use something more like 4K/20K and you should get a much better result. If you want to balance offset due to input bias current offset, use a resistor from the non-inverting input to ground.

With sensible resistors and 2V RMS in (2V peak => \$\sqrt 2 V_{RMS} = 1.414 V_{RMS}\$  =  would be better since it looks like it's just starting to clip):

[image]

With given resistors and 2V RMS in (the cut-off number on the left is -10V, so the vertical scale is different from the other graph).

[image]

The reverse curve when 'clipping' is because the input is actually driving the output into the opposite direction (non-inverting) against the output (which is limiting and thus in a kind of constant-current mode).